# Android Room get all times of todays insert

Tags: android, date, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to save data when user starts a specific activity and when he ends it and I want to calculate how many hours the user spent this day/week/month

I'm having a problem to extract this information.

This is my table:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "daily_activity_time_table")
     data class TimeTrack(


        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var activityId: Long = 0L,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time")     
        val startTimeMilli: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),  //i didnt find a better way to save date and time

        @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time")
        var endTimeMilli: Date = startTimeMilli,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "quality_rating")
        var sleepQuality: Int = -1
)
```

and I need a query to get the sum of today hours for example, I tried doing something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(end_time-start_time) from daily_activity_time_table where start_time = date('now') ")
        fun getTodayTime(): Long
```

I'm able to print to the screen the date and time with this convertor:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun convertLongToDateString(systemTime: Long): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM-dd-yyyy' Time: 'HH:mm")
        .format(systemTime).toString()
}
```

but cant find a way to print all the hours that the user used the activity *today*

Comment: check for convertor https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

Comment: Well, since your start time contains minutes and seconds it will never be equal to NOW. You will have to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format to neglect the time and only keep the date. Also the start date only gets a time and not the date as you just run `getMillis`. Please provide your intended data structure and the code where you insert a new entry

Comment: @Raghunandan
I added convertors but I cant figure out how they help me to extract all the activity's from today

Comment: @AviadHitner by writing proper sql queries. Convertor is for converting date to long and long back to date when you use it with data classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a small and very simplified project showing how to extract data from `Room` by a range of dates (represented as milliseconds since epoch)

https://github.com/or-dvir/RoomDate

Please note that this is NOT the proper way to set up `Room` database, and that this method has its limits (for example it does not take time zones into account).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just keep Room for storing and retreiving persistent data, and do the whole calculating things part in a different place (ie. your `Activity` or `ViewModel` or repository)

Something like

```
@Entity
class TimeTrack(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val startTime: Long,
    val endTime: Long,
    val sleepQuality: Int = -1
){
    val totalTime: Long
        get() = endTime - startTime
    
    // maybe this as well, gets the Local Date as LocalDate in case you want to filter by that
    val startDate: LocalDate
        get() = LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(startTime), ZonedDateTime.now().offset)
}
```

```
@Dao
interface TimeTrackDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM TimeTrack")
    suspend fun getTimeTracks(): List<TimeTrack>

    @Query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM TimeTrack ")
    suspend fun highestID(): Int

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun save(vararg consensus: TimeTrack)
}
```

and then after getting a start- and stop-time for your activity:

```
    // this gives a nice unambiguous timestamp
    val startTime = Instant.now().epochSecond
    val stopTime = Instant.now().epochSecond
    val tt = TimeTrack(timeTrackDao.highestID()+1,
                       startTime,
                       stopTime,
                       sleepQuality = -1)
    timeTrackDao.save(tt)

    fun totalTimeSpentAt(timeTrackList: List<TimeTrack>): Duration = Duration.ofSeconds(timeTrackList.map{it.totalTime}.sum())
```

Comment: I had a problem with .toLocalDate it wont let me use it as a method of "ofEpochSecond"

Comment: Sorry, I had that as an extension function. on the project I abused to quickly test that. `LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(startTime), ZonedDateTime.now().offset)` should work